# Spring properties file and spring reference

Tags: spring, properties-file

How to make reference link in properties file.
For example, I have spring config:

```
  <property name="velocityProperties">
       <value> 
         <entry key="ds.resource.loader.instance">
             <ref bean="databaseVelocityTemplateLoader"/>
         </entry>
         <entry key="ds.resource.loader.resource.table">
             <value>v_template</value>
         </entry>
         <entry key="ds.resource.loader.resource.keycolumn">
             <value>N_ID</value>
         </entry>
       <value>
   </property>
```

And I want to write this config in file:

```
ds.resource.loader.resource.keycolumn=N_ID
ds.resource.loader.resource.table=v_template
```

How to write this ref: `ds.resource.loader.instance` ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of a way built into Spring to do this, but you could extend the [PropertiesPlaceholderConfigurer](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html) and override the [convertPropertyValue() method](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyResourceConfigurer.html#convertPropertyValue%28java.lang.String%29) to try to resolve a property value to a bean name before doing the normal property replacement.